# Set Item and Text Height in Context Menu

Tags: android, android-menu, android-contextmenu

I didn't find a way to change the default Item height and text size of context menus. For me the items are far to high. Is there any way to achieve this?

```
protected void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu)
{
    MenuHandler handler = new MenuHandler();

    menu.add(0, R.id.duplicate_line, 0, R.string.duplicate_line).setOnMenuItemClickListener(handler);
    ...
```

I need the context menu for EditText Control. I tried to create a long click listener, it was ok, but the solution doesn't work for me, because the cursor position changed in the EditText Control, if I long clicked in the control and missed the old cursor position. (I need the cursor position unchanged, because I want to apply some function related to the original cursor position).

So my question is: is there any possibility to change text height, Item height... just in the contextmenu itself?

Thank you